# Oracle 12c installation on Debian 8

Tags: oracle, installation, debian

I'm just trying to install Oracle 12c Releas 2 on Debian 8. The following errors accure in the linking section of the installer process:

> INFO: 
>   e/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2/lib//libpls12.a(pfrfd.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.rodata' can not be used when making
>   a shared object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:
>   /storage/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2/lib//libpls12.a(pri.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata.str1.4' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need debian 8 for Oracle 12c ? if possible try with Redhat 7 / Oracle UEK 7 or Centos 7, which are **Oracle friendly** linux dstros.

Comment: Yes indeed, we only use Debian in our institution.